# Why v-text is not working to show a String

Tags: vue.js

I tried to show particular string using `v-text`. But it shows nothing.

Tried code

ccc.handlebars

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-text="getValues[0].value">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      'bulk': {{{bulks}}}
    },
    computed: {
      getValues: function() {
        return this.bulk;
      }
    },
    methods: {},
  });
</script>
```

`getValues` retuens JSON

```
[
  { name: "Dauth", age: "18", value: "TGFR123" }
]
```

I want to show `TGFR123` in the text box

Above `getValues` returns the correct JSON. But `v-text="getValues[0].value"` not shows the string. Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v-text` does not work on `input`.

If you want to set the value of an input use `:value` or `v-model`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bulk: [{
      name: "Dauth",
      age: "18",
      value: "TGFR123"
    }]
  },
  computed: {
    getValues: function() {
      return this.bulk;
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app">
  Bind : <input type="text" :value="getValues[0].value">
  v-model : <input type="text" v-model="getValues[0].value">
  <div>Result : {{getValues[0].value}}</div>
</div>
```

With v-model the data will be changed with the user input

[v-text](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-text)

[value binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `v-model` or `v-bind:value` to insert this value in your input

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bulk: [{id: 123, name: "Test", value: "NerF21_346"}]
  },
  computed: {
    getValues() {
      return this.bulk[0].value
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="getValues">
</div>
```

[v-model documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Text)